# How to improve performance by reducing DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, knockout.js

In the simple example below, Knockout calls `HTMLElement.appendChild` 18 times to render the template. It doesn't use `DocumentFragment`, so each of these 18 operations are made on the live DOM causing reflows. Ideally, there should be only one call to `appendChild` on the live DOM.

This really hurts performance, does anyone know how to reduce the damage?

---

[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/lizi/3/edit) with the code.

---

**JavaScript**

```
var viewModel = {
  people:[
    {name: 'Tim'},
    {name: 'John'},
    {name: 'Greg'}
  ]
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('list1'));
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id='list1' data-bind="foreach: { data: people }">
  <li>
      <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Didn't check the code above the \*\* KO \*\* part but here's the AngularJS version http://jsbin.com/lizi/4/

Comment: you can hide during updates to prevent re-layout...

Comment: @user1066946 Nice! Unfortunately, I'm working on an existing app and I'm not in position to change the framework/library right now.

Comment: @dandavis That might be a good idea! Do you know how to do it in KO (are there before & after rendering callbacks)?

Comment: sadly, i don't know any backbone tricks for this. i suppose you could do it yourself before setting model values, using a short timeout to un-hide it.

Comment: @dandavis timeout seems hackish, I'll check docs for something more reliable. Again, thanks for the tip!

Comment: There are [before and after rendering callbacks](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_4_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove) for KO templates.

Comment: If you remove the line breaks around the `li` it will not have to deal with those text nodes (so `<ul><li></li></ul>`). That brings it down to 10. The 1st one is actually copying the original `li` to a new `div` as part of storing it, so not appending to the document. The last 3 are unrelated to KO (just part of loading jQuery). So, there are only 6 (adding 3 `li`s and 3 text nodes for `text` binding.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer This is a great analysis, super useful. Thank you! I'm still making these X appends directly on the DOM though, so I will probably combine your tips with node hiding during rendering.

Answer (score 3):

My [Repeat plugin](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) provides a binding that can be used as an alternative to the `foreach` binding. It's faster in many cases, so you'll just need to experiment to compare the performance.

For comparison, here's how you'd bind your example using `repeat`:

```
<ul id='list1'>
  <li data-bind="repeat: people">
    <h3 data-bind="text: $item().name"></h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsbin.com/lizi/7/edit

Comment: Maybe you should show how much faster it is in jsperf.